# After installing Ubuntu 22.04 my keyboard backlight stopped working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, brightness, backlight

Recently, I installed Ubuntu on my galaxy book 3 360 and the backlight of the keyboard doesn´t work anymore. When I power my laptop all the keyboard lights up, so they are working but after sometime its turns off and the i cant get then on again by using the fn keys.

I already tried the xset the solution but it didn´t work.

Does anyone have other solutions?